UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 19-38: character maps to <undefined>
I am working on a Flask-based web application where users can upload images to predict using a machine learning model. The uploaded images are stored in a local directory, and predictions are made with a pre-trained model. However, when I hit the predict button
What is causing this UnicodeEncodeError?
How can I resolve this issue to ensure my application works correctly with image uploads and predictions?
Are there best practices for dealing with character encoding in a Flask environment, especially on Windows?
==app.py====
@app.route('/uploadimage', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_image():

        file = request.files['my_image']
        # Get the prediction
        predicted_label = predict_label(img_path)
        # Return the predicted label with a flash message
        flash(f"Prediction: {predicted_label}", "success")
        os.remove(img_path)  # Remove the temporary file after processing
    return render_template('uploadimage.html')  # For GET request, render the form


I am getting this error even i have set the environment variable "UTF-8"
Error
File "C:\Users\Subha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 122, in error_handler
raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Subha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 19-38: character maps to undefined.
============
Even i got a simplest code to test encoding
caption for that was "To test if your console can handle UTF-8, try outputting text with special characters or Unicode characters:"
print("UTF-8 test: àéîöü — 中文 — العربية")


Error is same for it as well
print("UTF-8 test: ����� � \u4e2d\u6587 � \u0627\u0644\u0639\u0631\u0628\u064a\u0629")
File "C:\Users\Subha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 20-21: character maps to 

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Don't expect anybody to go chasing after your screen shot.  Copy and paste the relevant text into the question.

The error trace shows that the error is coming from cp1252.py.  This indicates it's using the Windows code page 1252, not UTF-8 as you're expecting.  It also looks like you're using Python 3.11, which on Windows should be able to print any Unicode string to the console so I don't quite know why it's failing.

Add the following lines at the beginning of your Python script.
import sys

sys.stdout.reconfigure(encoding='utf-8')

sys.stderr.reconfigure(encoding='utf-8')

Description:- In Python, you can explicitly set the default encoding to UTF-8, which supports a wide range of characters.
It solved my problem.
